# Specified Cast Is Not Valid, C# Webpage

Tags: c#, casting

I am working on Web Page is visual studio using C#, and I am pulling the columns below into a collection of new authors.

I keep getting a `Specified Cast Is Not Valid error`.  I think it has to do with my int "au_id."My professor has given us a database where the id is an nvarchar, not an int, so I need to convert it so that it is. Below is the code:

```
colauthors.Add(new authors(
     (int)reader["au_id"],
     (string)reader["au_lname"],
     (string)reader["au_fname"],
     (string)reader["phone"],
     (string)reader["address"],
     (string)reader["city"],
     (string)reader["state"],
     (string)reader["zip"],
     (bool)reader["contract"]));
```

And this is how the columns are in the database along with their data types:

```
au_id nvarchar(50) 
au_lname nvarchar (50) 
au_fname nvarchar (50) 
phone char (12) 
address nvarchar (50) 
city nvarchar (50) 
state char (2) 
zip char (5) 
contract bit
```

I know that for contract the bit will be a bool, and I'm pretty sure that char's are strings.  So I am almost positive my error has to do with the id, I just can't figure out how to cast it correctly.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the au_id type is nvarchar in the db then it will fail for both of the enumerated conversions (ex. "abc" can't be converted to int). You could try int.tryparse wich in case of failure returns false allowing you to provide some alternate id.

Comment: +1 you're right, I initially misread OP's description of the table schema

Answer (score 1):

You must change the datatype of the `au_id` column to an integer (or related datatype), or parse the value as a string in c# as **Attila Kurucz** suggests.

There could also be problems if the `contract` or `au_id` column is `null`. Try this

```
(int)!reader.IsDbNull(reader.GetOrdinal("au_id")) && reader["au_id"]
...
(bool)!reader.IsDbNull(reader.GetOrdinal("contract")) && reader["contract"]
```

or this (although it will require you to tweak your `authors` class slightly).

```
(int?)reader["au_id"]
...
(bool?)reader["contract"]
```

To specify a default value in the event that a column is `null` try this.

```
((int?)reader["au_id"]) ?? 0
...
((bool?)reader["contract"]) ?? false
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!  I finally got it to display when I commented out my (int)reader["au_id"] line, so I know that the error is there.

Comment: Yes, the first one you suggested is what I needed! Thank you so much!

Comment: I used the first lines for both au_id and contract, but now I am getting an error: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' does not contain a definition for 'IsDbNull' and no extension method 'IsDbNull' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).